# In Job 14:17, what is the meaning of the phrase “my transgression is sealed up in a bag”?

Tags: job

In Job 14:17, it is written,

> My transgression is sealed up in a bag, and thou sewest up mine iniquity. <sup>KJV, 1769</sup>
>   חָתֻם בִּצְרוֹר פִּשְׁעִי וַתִּטְפֹּל עַל עֲוֹנִי
>   *ḥātum biṣrōwr pišʿî wattiṭpōl ʿal-ʿăwōnî*

What is the meaning of חָתֻם בִּצְרוֹר פִּשְׁעִי—“my transgression is sealed up in a bag,” in particular the phrase “in a bag”?

Answer (score 1):

'Putting in a bag' was an ancient manner to preserve (or, conserve) something not deserve to lose.
In Job 13:26 the patriarch believe God was striking him due to his juvenile sins. Moreover, verses 16-17 (of the 14th chapter) form a synonymic parallelism. Clearly, verse 16 speaks about the Job's conviction God is catching him on the wrong foot. And, in the next verse (17) he repeat - with other words - the same concept (also the second part, where he speaks about an error sewed up).

So, the sense would be: "You [God] have not forget my early errors [I repented], but you have preserved them until now."

Answer (score 0):

John Gill explains it this way

Job 14:17

> ***My transgression is sealed up in a bag***,. Denoting either the concealment of it, as in Hosea 13:12; not from God; nor in such sense sealed up as sin is by the sacrifice and satisfaction of Christ, who has thereby removed it out of the sight of divine justice; so that when it is sought for it shall not be found, nor any more seen, which is the sense of the phrase in Daniel 9:24; where the words, "to make an end of sin", may be rendered, to "seal them up"; but this Job would not have complained of; he means it was hid as in a bag from himself, or he knew not what it was; the transgression was sealed up from him, he was entirely ignorant of and unacquainted with what it was for which he was severely afflicted: or else his sense is, that God had taken strict notice of his transgressions, and had, as it were, put them up in a bag, and set a seal upon it, that none might be lost, but might be ready to be produced against him another day; in allusion, as it is thought, to bills of indictment put up in bags sealed, to be brought into courts of judicature at a proper time, for which they are reserved:
>
> ***and thou sewest up mine iniquity; in the bag*** in which it is sealed; not only did he seal up the bag, but sewed a cloth over it thus sealed, for greater security: or "thou sewest to mine iniquity"F13ותטפל על עוני "assuis iniquitati meae", Piscator; "et adjungis ad iniquitatem meam", Beza , or adds iniquity to iniquity, as in Psalms 69:27; as arithmeticians do, who add one number to another until it becomes a great sum; thus God, according to Job, tacked and joined one sin to another, till it became one large heap and pile, reaching to the heavens, and calling for vengeance; or, as Sephorno interprets it, joined sins of ignorance to sins of presumption; or rather sewed or added the punishment of sin to sin, or punishment to punishment; the Targum is
>
> "my transgression is sealed up in a book of remembrances, and thou hast joined it to my iniquities'

Job's transgressions were all numbered not one was passed by,they were sealed up so that none could be lost